# Hover effect won't trigger on image

Tags: html, css, image, hover, opacity

I have problem with my hover on img in my #picutre div. HTML:

```
<div id="picture">
      <img class="content_pic" src="image/exemple.jpg" alt="exemple"/>
      <img class="content_pic" src="image/exemple.jpg" alt="exemple"/>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
#picture {
    text-align:center;
}

#picture img {
    width:40%;
    height:40%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    opacity:0.4;
}

.content_pic:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

So i'm wondering why it doesn't work. I'm using Google Chrome, checked IE10 too but not working there too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#picture img` is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than `.content_pic:hover` so `opacity:0.4;` will always overwrite `opacity:1.0;`.

Use `#picture img:hover` instead.

Comment: I found my problem! I had #picture div in #content and #content had z-index: -1; which caused problem wit hover. You specification about id and class helped me too! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have given the picture img `opacity 0.4` and hover effect for `.content_pic:hover`  so this vl not work.

see the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/4z55sjn0/2/

Comment: @Lea cohen, Please go through with my code, what is wrong is that. i think its working perfectly.

Comment: I just formatted the code, didn't mean to change anything. If I accidently did, I'm sorry. You can rollback to your first version f you feel my edit was wrong.